# creating new UIView objects from XIB

Tags: ios, uiview, xib

I have a view created in xib with UIImageviews and UILabel as the subviews. From my code, is it possible to create a new view object every time i run a loop.Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new custom view named CustomView
Select class in XIB to CustomView.

Then load XIB name to a View object and can use in a loop

```
CustomView *aView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourXibName" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Using UINib is more efficient (it only loads the xib data into memory once, then instantiates new instances from there)

Answer (score 0):

When you have created a view and hooked it up via interface builder you can easily add views like

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++){
     UIView * newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:MyFrame];
     [myInterfaceBuilderView addSubview:newView];
}
```

Comment: initWithFrame don't create new view with XIB, just blank one